# Зачем нужны events?

Tags: c#, события

Поясните пожалуйста , зачем нам нужны events , если можно использовать делегаты?
Например:
вместо заморочек с событиями создать делегат, добавить в него нужные нам методы и сделать следующее :

```
...
if (myCondition) 
{
    myDelegate();
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Например: вместо заморочек с делегатами создать событие, добавить в него нужные нам обработчики.